# SSIS Package Fails To Run With Script Task

Tags: c#, ssis

I've got a Console app that tries to run an SSIS package (in Package Deployment Mode).  Both the console app and the SSIS package are located on my C: drive.  The code works as long as the called package doesn't contain a Script Task.  When the called package contains a Script Task, I get this error:

> *Package Execution results: The task has failed to load. The contact information for this task is "". 
> Package Execution results: There
> were errors during task validation. 
> Package Execution results: The
> package cannot execute because it contains tasks that failed to load.*

I've tried running the called package from SSDT and it runs successfully.  But when run from the code below, it fails.  Based on answers from similar posts, I've tried changing the TargetServerVersion property of the called package.  But the same errors still occur.  Both the console app and the called Script Task use .NET Framework 4.7.2 as the target framework.

Any idea what could be wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace PackageTester
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string SSISPackagePath = @"C:\-------\console_app_test_2.dtsx";
            string datafilePath = @"C:\-------\datafiles\my_data_file.csv";

            string results = FireSSIS(SSISPackagePath, datafilePath);

            Console.WriteLine(results);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string FireSSIS(string packagePath, string FilePath)  
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                Application app = new Application();
                Package package = null;

                package = app.LoadPackage(packagePath, null);

                Variables myVars = package.Variables;

                myVars["SourceFilePath"].Value = FilePath;

                DTSExecResult results = package.Execute(null, myVars, null, null, null);

                if (results == DTSExecResult.Success)
                {
                    result = "Success";
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (DtsError local_DtsError in package.Errors)
                    {
                        result += string.Concat($"Package Execution results: { local_DtsError.Description }\r\n");
                    }
                }                
            }

            catch (DtsException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
            }

            return result;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a Migration issue.  The dtsx file contain migration instructions (xml).  So it sound like there were updates to database and the updates are failing. I've seen a number of migration posting recently and have been suspecting the migration changes Microsoft has made are not very robust. In  one case a tracked issue to migration not connecting to the updated database.  The connection was failing.  So I would recommend checking the connection string you are using and check if you can still connect to database with the connection string.

Comment: @jdweng - I can run the package successfully in Data Tools so the connection strings are accurate.  But when run from the console app on the same machine, the package fails.  If I remove the Script Task from the package, the console app runs the package successfully.  There must be something about the Script Task that's causing this error.

Comment: Are you running from Visual Studio or from and executable?  Migration may need an Admin to run.  Inside VS you do not automatically run with Admin.  To run code with Admin you need to right click the VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  A Net executable outside VSW will run with Admin privilege's.

Comment: Running inside Visual Studio or from an executable with admin rights produces the same error.

Comment: The check if connection string still works.

Comment: Connection string to package is correct.  Connection string to data file is correct.

Comment: I meant the connection string to the database.  To perform a migration you need to be able to connect to the database and then make the updates to the mapping file.  So a comparison of the c# classes, mapping file, and database need to be consistent.  The first step in checking/updating is you need to be able to connect to database.  If the connection works than check the Database log files for errors.

Comment: There are no database connections in this package.  It's an SSIS package that has one task - a Script Task - that validates the contents of the passed-in file.  If you're referring to SSISDB, this package is deployed in Package Deployment Mode which doesn't use SSISDB at all.

Comment: See following : https://docs.fileformat.com/database/dtsx/?force_isolation=true

Comment: Link doesn't help answer my question.  It only describes the .dtsx format.  It says nothing about running packages outside of SSDT or troubleshooting failing script tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation. Any package with a script task will fail to run outside a "proper" integration services installation. It is a licensing issue to my knowledge. There might be additional limitations as well.

Comment: Ok.  Makes sense.  Perhaps I can change the design so that the console app calls an Agent job which in turn calls the SSIS package.  I'll test that out.  Thanks.